# Converting Snake Case to Lower Camel Case (lowerCamelCase)

Tags: python, python-2.7, camelcasing, snakecasing

What would be a good way to convert from snake case (`my_string`) to lower camel case (myString) in Python 2.7?

The obvious solution is to split by underscore, capitalize each word except the first one and join back together.

However, I'm curious as to other, more idiomatic solutions or a way to use `RegExp` to achieve this (with some case modifier?)

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing to achieve this out of the box. Did you try implementing your own solution?

Comment: edited my question, I know there is no built in, I wanted to find a nice implementation

Comment: I don't think this question is 'off topic' in any way.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

```
def to_camel_case(snake_str):
    return "".join(x.capitalize() for x in snake_str.lower().split("_"))

def to_lower_camel_case(snake_str):
    # We capitalize the first letter of each component except the first one
    # with the 'capitalize' method and join them together.
    camel_string = to_camel_case(snake_str)
    return snake_str[0].lower() + camel_string[1:]
```

Example:

```
In [11]: to_lower_camel_case('snake_case')
Out[11]: 'snakeCase'

In [12]: to_lower_camel_case('SNAKE_Case')
Out[12]: 'snakeCase'

In [13]: to_lower_camel_case('SNAKE_CASE')
Out[13]: 'snakeCase'
```

Comment: What other datataypes would camelCasing be applicable to?

Comment: Well, that's not really idiomatic Python, which generally adheres to the "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" principle. With >3.5 you could add type hints if you want type safety, but doing type checking with if-else for functions that are as clear-cut as this (what else could you possible camelCase other than strings?) is just bad style and excessive verbosity in my book.

Comment: Just wanted to second jbaiter here. It's not the responsibility of `to_camel_case` to ensure the input is a string, it's the responsibility of calling code. Passing a non-string will raise an exception, which is good. That's what exceptions are for.

Comment: @stelios Not even. What about empty strings? And what would you do otherwise? Because thus you're returning a `None`. You can't prevent any single error. If you try it you will only end up shadowing its source. That's Python, not Java. You don't have to avoid exceptions, you have to treat them.

Comment: Bit of a corner case, but if you expect `_bar` to become `bar` instead of `Bar`, then make a slight tweak: `components = snake_str.lstrip('_').split('_')`

Comment: I think that it's more correct to call `str.capitalize()` than `str.title()` as the `title()` implies that there are multiple word in a given string, but there should be no space in any of the components.

Comment: Unless I'm confused the call to `snake_str.lower()` is redundant because `.capitalize()` will lowercase everything after the first character in each word anyway.

Answer (score 29):

Here's yet another take, which works only in Python 3.5 and higher:

```
def camel(snake_str):
    first, *others = snake_str.split('_')
    return ''.join([first.lower(), *map(str.title, others)])
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehension when a generator would do (i.e, `join(...)` is better than `join([...])` here, because it works without creating a list).

Comment: You are absolutely right, however that does not apply in this particular case, as what is passed to the `join` method is not a comprehension but a regular list. If you want to avoid creating an in-memory list you could use use `itertools.chain`, but then if you are concerned about memory footprint when converting snake to camel case you have much bigger problems. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I misread it (because I got here looking for the PascalCase instead of camelCase). No, this is fine.

Answer (score 26):

A little late to this, but I found this on /r/python a couple days ago:

```
pip install pyhumps
```

and then you can just do:

```
import humps

humps.camelize('jack_in_the_box')  # jackInTheBox
# or
humps.decamelize('rubyTuesdays')  # ruby_tuesdays
# or
humps.pascalize('red_robin')  # RedRobin
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, and as a bonus if you pass in a dictionary, it will camelize the keys but leave the values. Which is perfect for anyone building an API in python but wanting the JSON response to be more JavaScript friendly.

Comment: this also takes care of more complicated cases like `_response` or `APIResponse`

Answer (score 13):

another one liner

```
def to_camel_case(snake_string):
    return snake_string.title().replace("_", "")
```

Comment: First char is Upper Case.

Comment: Useful if you want to convert to a class name, for instance.

Comment: While the OP asks for lower-camel-case, this is actually the first stackoverflow example that came up when searching "convert snake case to camel case python".  This is what I actually wanted though, so I'm glad it's here.

Answer (score 9):

Obligatory one-liner:

```
import string

def to_camel_case(s):
    return s[0].lower() + string.capwords(s, sep='_').replace('_', '')[1:] if s else s
```

Comment: This method fails when having a leading underscore (first letter gets omitted).

Comment: Even shorter: `return re.sub(r'_([a-z])', lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), name)` [(see here)](http://rodic.fr/blog/camelcase-and-snake_case-strings-conversion-with-python/)

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> snake_case = "this_is_a_snake_case_string"
>>> l = snake_case.split("_")
>>> print l[0] + "".join(map(str.capitalize, l[1:]))
'thisIsASnakeCaseString'
```

Answer (score 4):

## for one-line fans..

```py
''.join((wd.title() if i else wd) for (i,wd) in enumerate(string.split('_')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on Steve's answer, this version should work:

```
def to_camel_case(snake_case_string):
    titleCaseVersion =  snake_case_string.title().replace("_", "")
    camelCaseVersion = titleCaseVersion[0].lower() + titleCaseVersion[1:]
    return camelCaseVersion
```

Answer (score 3):

*it this too simple?*

snake_case is already lowercase. `my_string`

So if we title the string and remove the underscores `MyString`

then replace the first character `M` with the original `m` we're done.

```
scase = "my_string"
ccase = scase[0] + scase.title().replace('_', '')[1:]
```

output:
`myString`

Answer (score 2):

```
def toCamel(snake)
    return ''.join( word.capitalize()
                    for word in snake.split('_') )
```

Allow underscore to be escaped by a preceding underscore (e.g. 'Escaped__snake' would become 'Escaped_Snake', while 'usual_snake' becomes 'UsualSnake'. Include ternary test for blank.

```
def toCamel(escaped_snake)
    return ''.join( (word.capitalize(), '_')[word=='')
                    for word in escaped_snake.split('_') )
```

Don't capitalize the 1st segment (i.e, 'tHERE_is_a_snake' becomes 'thereIsASnake')

```
def toCamel(esCAPed_snake)
    words = esCAPed_snake.split('_')
    return words[0].lower() + ''.join( (word.capitalize(), '_')[word=='')
                                       for word in words[1:] )
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally use this solution since it is a rolling transformation:

```
from functools import reduce

def camelize(snake_string: str) -> str:
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.capitalize(), snake_string.split('_'))
```

Comment: This solution capitalizes the first word if there is a leading underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using regular expressions:

```
import re

def snake_to_camel(text):
    return re.sub('_([a-zA-Z0-9])', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pydash` if you are familiar with `lodash`.

`pip install pydash` first.

```
import pydash  # pip install pydash

assert pydash.snake_case("WriteLine") == "write_line"
assert pydash.snake_case("writeLine") == "write_line"
assert pydash.camel_case("write_line") == "writeLine"
assert pydash.upper_first(pydash.camel_case("write_line")) == "WriteLine"
```

https://github.com/dgilland/pydash

https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://pypi.org/project/pydash/

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_camel_case(snake_str):
    components = snake_str.split('_')
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.title(), components[1:], components[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using list comprehensions:

```
def snake_to_camel_case(text_snake):
    return '{}{}'.format(
        text_snake[:1].lower(),
        text_snake.title().replace('_', '')[1:],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to convert a whole file with bunch of snake case parameters into camel case. The solution by [Mathieu Rodic](http://rodic.fr/blog/camelcase-and-snake_case-strings-conversion-with-python/) worked best. Thanks.

Here is a little script to use it on files.

```
import re

f = open("in.txt", "r")
words = f.read()

def to_camel_case3(s):
    return re.sub(r'_([a-z])', lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), s)

f = open("out.txt", "w")
f.write(to_camel_case3(words))
```