# How to return variable names in camelCase given a string with phrases seperates by semi-colons?

Tags: python, string

How can I make each phrase in the string into camelCase and get rid of the colons? s = 'num things;perc rate;rate'

It should return ['numThings', 'percRate', 'rate']

Here is some sample code I am trying to work on:

```
def createVars(s):
    varlst = []
    varlst = s.split(';')
    try:
        for words in varlst:
            words.title()
            words.strip()
    except ValueError:
        print('String not entered')
    return varlst
```

Comment: Note that neither `title()` nor `strip()` are inplace functions, so your code wouldn't work even if it was correct. Additionally, the first letter is also capitalized - not what you want.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I realize that but I just don't know how I would change the words to make it like that.

Comment: The answers here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053707. Not exactly the same, but close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that neither `title()` nor `strip()` are in-place functions, so you'd need to assign them back. Furthermore, you'd need to somehow lowercase the first letter before returning a result.

You could probably do this in a single line, but here's an old fashioned approach (!) with a function and `yield`.

```
def foo(string):
    for x in string.split(';'):
        y = x.title().replace(' ', '')  
        yield y[0].lower() + y[1:]     # amazingly, this works for one length strings too
```

---

```
x = 'num things;perc rate;rate'

print(list(foo(x)))
['numThings', 'percRate', 'rate']
```