# Converting snake_case to lowerCamelCase

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have defined a dataclass in which all variable are in `snake_case`. Whereas when I am returning my object I want to return everything in lowerCamerCase. But the problem is then nesting is very deep. Is there any way to automate this.

Although I have defined upper response object in camelCase what can I do for others.

```
#My json looks like
{
"highLevelObj1" : {
                      "low_level_obj1" : 1,
                      "low_level_obj2" : 2
                  },
"someRandomText" : {
                      "some_random_info1" : 1,
                      "some_random_info2" : 2
                  }
}
```

My expected output is

```
{
"highLevelObj1" : {
                      "lowLevelObj1" : 1,
                      "lowLevelObj2" : 2
                  },
"someRandomText" : {
                      "someRandomInfo1" : 1,
                      "someRandomInfo2" : 2
                  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define a method to convert a snake_case string to a lowerCamelCase string
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053800/5712576)), then I think the easiest way would be to convert your json into a string convert it to camelCase then convert it back to a dictionary

```
import json

def to_camel_case(snake_str):
    components = snake_str.split('_')
    return components[0] + ''.join(x.title() for x in components[1:])

my_dict = {
"highLevelObj1" : {
                      "low_level_obj1" : 1,
                      "low_level_obj2" : 2
                  },
"someRandomText" : {
                      "some_random_info1" : 1,
                      "some_random_info2" : 2
                  }
}
string_dict = json.dumps(my_dict)
string_dict_camel_case = to_camel_case(string_dict)
my_dict = json.loads(string_dict_camel_case)
```

Output :

```
{'highLevelObj1': {'lowLevelObj1': 1, 'LowLevelObj2': 2},
 'Somerandomtext': {'SomeRandomInfo1': 1, 'SomeRandomInfo2': 2}}
```

Comment: But if value in dict is in camel case. It might will affect that as well..right?

Comment: It will convert any string in snake_case to camelCase

Comment: Also if I will have key say `key` then it will throw an error